# C# Database Application Concurrency

Tags: c#, concurrency

I wrote a multi user app in c# some time age using SQL Server 2005 express as back-end.

I have a Orders collection. In order to use this class you would need to instantiate it and just call the Load(CustomerCode) method in order to populate the collection with the specified customers`s orders.

**My question:**

How do I enforce concurrency, so that only 1 user can request a Orders collection for a specific customer? When the user is done with the object(when the object is set to null),
I will need to make it available again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement the [Pessimistic Offline Lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html) pattern.

Essentially you have a table that you put records in that represent a "lock" on records in other tables.  When you want to edit a record, you check to see if there's a lock in the lock table first, and react accordingly in your domain logic/UI.

It doesn't have to be a database, it could be an in-memory cache.  When I say "table" in my example, I mean a logical table, not necessarily a database one.

> Pessimistic Offline Lock prevents
>   conflicts by avoiding them altogether.
>   It forces a business transaction to
>   acquire a lock on a piece of data
>   before it starts to use it, so that,
>   most of the time, once you begin a
>   business transaction you can be pretty
>   sure you'll complete it without being
>   bounced by concurrency control.

Comment: Sounds good, but do you perhaps have a link to some code where this has been implemented ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a link to a code sample, but if you have a read of Fowler's book from my link, that is full of code samples.  They might even be available for download on the internet - Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture.